# differentiate a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

how can I differentiate a function in matlab? I tried with:

```
syms x;
f = 3x^2 + 2;
A = diff(f);
disp(A);
```

My problem is now I want to give x a value after (for example A(x = 1) and I don't know how.

Comment: So... `subs(A,x,1)`?

Comment: .....`A = 6*x?`

Answer (score 2):

First, there's an error in your code, you can't *imply* multiplication, you need to write `3*x^2` rather than `3x^2`.

Also, in case you feed the function a vector rather than scalar, you should use element-wise operations (including a `.` before powers, multiplication etc.) so this becomes `3*x.^2`.

Other than that, 2 options:

```
syms x;
f = 3*x.^2 + 2;
```

1) define `A` like you did and use `subs` to substitute `x` for, say, `1`.

```
A = diff(f);
subs(A,x,1);
```

2) define `A` as an anonymous function and call it more easily.

```
A = @(y) subs(diff(f),x,y)
```

Now `A` can be easily called with different values

```
A(1) 
ans = 6

A(2)
ans = 12
```

Links to documentation on element-wise ops, `subs` and anonymous functions:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html 
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: How can I differentiate a function-handle like @(x) x^3 + 2 ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you have the symbolic maths toolbox, you can do the above? You don't need an anonymous function if you define it as a symbolic function like in your question...

Comment: I want to make a function in which I can input my function and afaik this only work with function-handle.

Comment: This is a different question to what you asked, I advise looking into `matlabfunction` https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html to tackle that, or `diff` for some basic numerical differentiation techniques depending on how accurate your answer needs to be... https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.htmlhttps://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code like this:

```
syms x;
f = 3*x^2 + 2;    % You missed a * here
A(x) = diff(f);   % This creates a symfun
A(1)              % This gives the value of A at x=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`matlabfunction`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) function.

> matlabFunction Generate a MATLAB file or anonymous function from a sym